# New line not working in PHP 5.6

Tags: newline, php-5.6

Here i am using PHP 5.6 version in that i am trying to do line break but it is not happening , i having text like `Gshdhdhhdhdhhdhdhd\nGdghdhdhhdhd\nGdgdhfhhdhd\nGgdhdhhdd\nGgdhdhdhhd\nGe hdhdhdhd` using this text `\n` means new line should start ,so i am using `str_replace` but it not working

> My Code

```
echo  str_replace ('\r\n','<br>','Gshdhdhhdhdhhdhdhd\nGdghdhdhhdhd\nGdgdhfhhdhd\nGgdhdhhdd\nGgdhdhdhhd\nGe hdhdhdhd');
```

> Another method

```
echo  nl2br ("Gshdhdhhdhdhhdhdhd\nGdghdhdhhdhd\nGdgdhfhhdhd\nGgdhdhhdd\nGgdhdhdhhd\nGe hdhdhdhd");
```

Comment: With str_replace, try making the search string '\n' instead of '\r\n'.

Comment: I searched i am not getting answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are outputting this on an html page use the break tag 
 I do this all the time in my test suites for debugging.

```
echo "Some text want a newline<br>next text want another newline<br>";
```

the \n and \r\n are for text files.